# Apollo - update() method getting called twice, both times with optimistic/fake data

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo, aws-appsync, vue-apollo

I'm completely stuck on an Apollo problem, for which I've opened a GitHub issue and had zero response on.

I'm calling an Apollo mutation, using `optimisticResponse`. The way it's supposed to work, as I understand it, is that `update()` gets called twice: first with the optimistic data, then again with the actual data coming in from the network.

But for some reason, my code is not working like this. I'm getting two `update()` calls, both with the optimistic data.

Here's a repo that demonstrates this behavior: https://github.com/ffxsam/apollo-update-bug

1. yarn && yarn dev
2. Open in browser, open console
3. Enter some text and hit enter
4. Repeat above
5. Notice the error in the console about duplicate keys. This is happening because the temporary ID "??" is not being replaced with the real UUID
   (optional) You can open Vue DevTools if available and inspect the data to see it's incorrect

Comment: Can you see if this PR, merged today, resolves your issue: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-js/pull/43

Comment: I know this isn't really a "solution" but it looks like the `aws-appsync@deepdish` tag has a fix (at least it seems to work for me now. I don't believe that this is a stable branch, so buyer beware in production, but it's working for me as of now. Source: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-js/issues/170

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I was doing some digging and I think I found the source of the problem.
Unfortunately, I don't have a solution.

**In short,** the problem might be with a network link called `OfflineLink` that is used by `aws-appsync`.

### Explanation

`aws-appsync` has an ApolloLink called `OfflineLink` that intervenes with the `request` function.

What happens is something like this:

1. you call `$apollo.mutate(...)`
2. `ApolloClient.QueryManager` initializes the mutation that triggers your `update` the first time with the optimistic response. That is happening inside ApolloClient data store, [markMutationInit](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/master/packages/apollo-client/src/data/store.ts#L74) calls [markMutationResult](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/master/packages/apollo-client/src/data/store.ts#L114) that [calls your update](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/master/packages/apollo-client/src/data/store.ts#L178%20store%20line%20178).
3. The graphql operation executes and reaches the `OfflineLink` in the network chain.
4. `OfflineLink` creates a new observer and [dispatches the mutation](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-js/blob/master/packages/aws-appsync/src/link/offline-link.js#L61) info as an action.
5. The next line of `OfflineLink` calls the observer's `next` function with the `optimisticResponse` **as if it was the execution result!**
6. This triggers your `update` the **second time** with the result which is actually the `optimisticResponse`.
7. `OfflineLink` calls the observer's `complete` which resolves your promise.
8. `console.log('done!'...`

Meanwhile, `OfflineLink` prevents the original mutation from even sending the request, and a new mutation is generated and sent with the options you've given it.

Comment: This was totally the issue. THANK YOU.

Comment: Can you check the latest PR that was merged and see if the issue still exists? You can find it here: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-js/pull/43

Comment: Wonderful. This is mainly causing me a problem in create mutation - my app temporarily shows duplicate data. It was a simple workaround for me to check if the data already exists and only showing optimisticResponse for the first time. Update query's server response won't update the data but the data is re-requested from the server immediately that anyway. Hopefully this issue gets fixed soon!