# Apollo mutate calling update four times for a single mutation

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, aws-appsync, vue-apollo

Every time I add a new item in my app, the mutation calls `update()` *four* times, for some reason. The first two are optimistic data, and in the second batch, one is optimistic and one is real data from the network. I can't make any sense of this. The new item being created shows up twice on the page.

This is my mutation:

```
mutation CreateTrack($name: String!, $trackNum: Int, $s3Key: String!) {
  createTrack(name: $name, trackNum: $trackNum, s3Key: $s3Key) {
    trackId
    name
    createdAt
    duration
    trackNum
    s3Key
    isProcessing
    didProcessingFail
  }
}
```

And this is the mutation code:

```
createTrack({ name, s3Key }) {
  const newTrack = {
    name,
    s3Key,
  };

  this.$apollo
    .mutate({
      mutation: createTrackMutation,
      variables: newTrack,
      update: (store, { data: { createTrack } }) => {
        console.log('this is dumb', JSON.stringify(createTrack, null, 2));
        const variables = {
          limit: this.pageSize,
          order: this.order === 'ascending' ? 'asc' : 'desc',
          sortBy: this.sortBy,
        };
        const data = store.readQuery({
          query: listTracksQuery,
          variables,
        });
        data.listTracks.items.push(createTrack);
        store.writeQuery({
          query: listTracksQuery,
          variables,
          data,
        });
      },
      optimisticResponse: {
        __typename: 'Mutation',
        createTrack: {
          __typename: 'Track',
          ...newTrack,
          trackId: '??',
          createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
          isProcessing: true,
          didProcessingFail: false,
          duration: null,
          trackNum: 999,
        },
      },
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log('done!', data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('error', err);
    });
},
```

And finally, here are the console logs for calling mutate *once*:

```
this is dumb {
  "__typename": "Track",
  "name": "small2.wav",
  "s3Key": "staging/audio/10e3e675-e7a6-41dc-a8fb-686ad683e40e.wav",
  "trackId": "??",
  "createdAt": "2018-03-05T03:30:18.246Z",
  "isProcessing": true,
  "didProcessingFail": false,
  "duration": null,
  "trackNum": 999
}

this is dumb {
  "__typename": "Track",
  "name": "small2.wav",
  "s3Key": "staging/audio/10e3e675-e7a6-41dc-a8fb-686ad683e40e.wav",
  "trackId": "??",
  "createdAt": "2018-03-05T03:30:18.246Z",
  "isProcessing": true,
  "didProcessingFail": false,
  "duration": null,
  "trackNum": 999
}

done! {data: {...}}

this is dumb {
  "__typename": "Track",
  "name": "small2.wav",
  "s3Key": "staging/audio/10e3e675-e7a6-41dc-a8fb-686ad683e40e.wav",
  "trackId": "??",
  "createdAt": "2018-03-05T03:30:18.246Z",
  "isProcessing": true,
  "didProcessingFail": false,
  "duration": null,
  "trackNum": 999
}

this is dumb {
  "trackId": "2b3de8ac-d145-4da6-b522-27e5413d43e1",
  "name": "small2.wav",
  "createdAt": "2018-03-05T03:30:18.627Z",
  "duration": null,
  "trackNum": 999,
  "s3Key": "staging/audio/10e3e675-e7a6-41dc-a8fb-686ad683e40e.wav",
  "isProcessing": true,
  "didProcessingFail": null,
  "__typename": "Track"
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think it's the same issue I described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48989517/2805067
I think the PR (in the comment there) fixed a related issue that `update` wasn't called. So now you see it is called (the 3rd and 4th times) from the second mutation that is created internally by `aws-appsync`.

Comment: So the PR fixed one issue but created another, maybe? The item is being shown twice on the web page, which shouldn't be happening.

Comment: I've edited my post to clarify that there is an actual issue with how the data is displayed on the page.. so it's not just an internal thing.

Comment: I don't think the PR created a new issue. It was just a partial fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just chatted through this with the Engineer that worked on this code. What you're seeing is the bookeeping process that the AWS AppSync SDK process uses under the covers to ensure data integrity. It is **NOT** actually running a mutation 4 times against your API.

When the AppSync client gets an optimistic response the update function runs twice - once for the local response and once for the network response. This is standard Apollo behavior. What the AppSync client does under the covers is on the first optimistic response, we treat it as if it were the network response and store the data in a persistent storage medium (local storage for web, Async Storage for React Native) to allow optimistic UI when in an offline state. This is essentially an "outbox" that the data first gets written to when offline (currently the implementation uses Redux Offline) and if you disable offline with `disableOffline:true` you will no longer see this behavior.

When you come back online, the synchronization process gets executed and you see another mutation message (which is actually the original mutation) of the client sending this to the server and the appropriate response.

Note that if you are creating unique IDs in your optimistic response on the client AND also creating unique IDs on the server, for instance using the `$util.autoId()` then you could have duplicate records as we will not overwrite any local data you've explicitly assigned an ID. You can do invalidation of any locally-created IDs if you wish by using the **Offline-enabled put item** and **Offline-enabled response** templates in the DynamoDB resolvers for AppSync which use an ephemeral key called `relayState` (that you'll need to add as a field for the type you're creating) that you can use to track the local ID and match it up with the ID that was created at the server.

There are more additions we're going to be making to this bookeeping process in the future and would welcome suggestions in our GitHub issues repo: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-js/issues

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Richard. I am trying to get my head around this as well as get offline mutation persistence guaranteed. Am I right in understanding that the AwsApolloClient does this as well as takes over for the job of something like apollo-cache-persist?

Comment: @CarlLippert yes that is correct, AWS AppSync client automatically persists the cache to disk, handles offline mutations, conflict resolution, synchronization, etc.You can think of it as a "plug in" that works with the base Apollo client.